# Sum pooling in tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Is there an existing implementation of sum pooling in tensorflow? When searching the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/pool), it seems that only average and max pooling operations are supported.

I have a NHWC tensor where each HxW matrix is a probability map which I would like to downsample via 2x2 sum pooling. If a sum pooling function does not exist in tensorflow, is there another way I could implement this downsampling operation using the Python API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing in tensorflow at the moment. The next best thing is probably to just multiply the output of an average pooling by 4. Element-wise multiplication is fast enough not to worry about this added step.

You *do* loose a pair of bits of precision in the process though.

An alternative would be to compute the sum yourself, e.g.

```
y = (x[:, 0::2, 0::2] +
     x[:, 1::2, 0::2] +
     x[:, 0::2, 1::2] +
     x[:, 1::2, 1::2])
```

It should be slower than the previous solution, but the precision may be slightly better, if that is important to you.

Comment: Good logic on that mean pool and then multiplying by the size! kudos

Comment: The precision shouldn't matter too much so I will make use of your average pooling solution in my implementation. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't even need to multiply by kernel size, especially if you're using something like BatchNorm to scale the layer output.

Comment: Multiplying by the size gives incorrect results depending on the padding that it used. Specifically, the average is computed over all elements within the boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

User already told you that you can leverage avg pooling to get sum pooling. He also mentioned that you might loose precision (but this is highly unlikely and in most of the cases irrelevant).

Here is another easy approach. You can use 2d convolution with strides to calculate sum pooling. Your kernel would be a matrix of ones.

Comment: Another nice solution, I would assume this has the same speed as average pooling minus the division?

Comment: @Salvador Dali That is simply not true. You end up doing more multiplications with a convolution kernel. Probably not an issue for `2x2` pooling, but still.

Comment: @user1735003 oh, yes. My bad. I forgot that it will multiply by 1 every element... Thanks

Comment: Though this only works if your input has only 1 channel, right?